# C# десериализация динамического объекта из json

Tags: c#, json

Я отправляю данные в формате json строки. Есть два класса: **SendData**(*универсальный упаковщик, оболочка*) и **Message**(*непосредственно информация*). И мне хочется, чтоб SendData в качестве данных мог иметь не только тип Message, но и любой другой. А на стороне получателя, я уже сам разберусь с типами. Поэтому я выбрал такой вариант:

```
namespace Serializer
{
    public class SendData // контейнер
    {
        public dynamic Data; // Динамический, чтоб хранить любой тип

        public DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;

        public SendData(object data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }
    }
}

namespace Serializer.Data
{
    public class Message // это уже сами данные
    {
        public string SenderLogin;
        public string Text;
        public DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;

        public Message(string text, string senderLogin)
        {
            Text = text;
            SenderLogin = senderLogin;
        }

    }
}
```

Я использую Newtonsoft.Json; который сериализует и десериализует эти объекты. Ошибка в том, что при десериализации строки я получаю объект **SendData**, в котором поле с объектом Message остается в виде **Object**, а не экземпляра **Message**.

**Пример**

```
Message message = new Message(text, Name);
SendData sendData = new SendData(message);

string data = SerializeService.Serialize(sendData);
SendData abc = SerializeService.Deserialize(data);
```

Есть вариант, чтоб хранить тип в отдельном поле, а на стороне получателя уже сравнить типы и приводить к нужному, но думаю я, что библиотека и сама может этим заняться

Comment: [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо. То, что было нужно!!